# Serilog text formatting to contain valid json output

Tags: c#, .net-5, serilog

I am logging with Serilog and have a (text) file sink with an output template and a console logger.

The output template of the text file logger:

```
"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}|{Level:u3}|{SourceContext}|{Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}"
```

The output template of the console logger:

```
"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3} {SourceContext} {Message:lj}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}"
```

Now we try (for the sake of easiness) to log some class data in JSON format. We want it as JSON beacuse we try to extract the data later from the log files.

The sample logging code is easy enough:

```
protected void DoTestLogs()
{

  Logger.LogInformation("HERE IT IS");

  Logger.LogInformation("HERE IT IS {@Foo}", new { Foo = "bar" });

  int x = 1;
  string y = "2";

  Logger.LogInformation("HERE IS ANOTHER ONE {@Other}", new { x, y });

  var data = new My.Data
  {
    Name = "my data",
    IsValid = true,
    Value = 27.82859584
  };

  Logger.LogInformation("HERE IS DATA {@Data}", data);
  
}
```

The console output looks valid as expected (except the serialzed type of data which I could ignore)

```
08:09:38.880 INF My.Test HERE IT IS
08:09:38.884 INF My.Test HERE IT IS {"Foo": "bar"}
08:09:38.888 INF My.Test HERE IS ANOTHER ONE {"x": 1, "y": "2"}
08:09:38.889 INF My.Test HERE IS DATA {"Name": "my data", "Value": 27.82859584, "IsValid": true, "$type": "Data"}
```

But the json in the text file log seems to be "randomly" invalid. I can't explain why quotes are there or not

```
2023-01-27 08:09:38.880|INF|My.Test|HERE IT IS
2023-01-27 08:09:38.884|INF|My.Test|HERE IT IS { Foo: "bar" }
2023-01-27 08:09:38.888|INF|My.Test|HERE IS ANOTHER ONE { x: 1, y: "2" }
2023-01-27 08:09:38.889|INF|My.Test|HERE IS DATA Data { Name: "my data", Value: 27.82859584, IsValid: True }
```

Does anyone have a hint how I could trick the file sink to put quotes around the names like Foo, x, y ... as the console sink does?

---

In case anyone want's to reproduce it and doesn't have a serilog setup at hand: here is the setup.

First create a new project from the "ASP.NET Core Web API" template. Then delete the WeatherForecast.cs and the WeatherForecastController.

Add the Serilog nuget to the cs.proj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Configure Serilog via the appsettings.json

```
{

  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3} {SourceContext} {Message:lj}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "logs/log.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}|{Level:u3}|{SourceContext}|{Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Integrate Serilog in the Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stackoverflow.Question75255058
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog
                (
                    (context, services, configuration) =>
                        configuration                            
                            .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                            .ReadFrom.Services(services)
                )
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

No need for changes in the StartUp.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stackoverflow.Question75255058
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Stackoverflow.Question75255058", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Stackoverflow.Question75255058 v1"));
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Create an new OutputController and the My.Data class under controllers

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stackoverflow.Question75255058.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class LogOutputController : ControllerBase
    {

        public readonly ILogger<LogOutputController> Logger;

        public LogOutputController(ILogger<LogOutputController> logger)
        {
            Logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("HERE IT IS");

            Logger.LogInformation("HERE IT IS {@Foo}", new { Foo = "bar" });

            int x = 1;
            string y = "2";

            Logger.LogInformation("HERE IS ANOTHER ONE {@Other}", new { x, y });

            var data = new My.Data
            {
                Name = "my data",
                IsValid = true,
                Value = 27.82859584
            };

            Logger.LogInformation("HERE IS DATA {@Data}", data);

            return NoContent();
        }
    }
}

namespace My
{
    public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Start the application and execute the controller action provided by Swagger.

Comment: Your own question shows that Serilog serializes objects as proper JSON. Don't try to double-serialize them. Your last call isn't serializing a JSON object, it's serializing a *string*. `"randomly" invalid.` on the contrary, that's what would happen if you serialized a string with any JSON parser.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  But wouldn't proper json contain quotes arount x and y on ANOTHER ONE in the file?

Comment: You're serializing a string as JSON, not an object. Why are you doing this at all?

Comment: which one do you mean? HERE IS A JSON STRING was just for cross checking. My problems are HERE IS DATA, HERE IS ANOTHER ONE and HERE IT IS where I would expect quotes around the field names e.g Foo, x, y, Name, Value in the output of the file as it is in the console

Comment: There's some confusion about what JSON is and how serialization works. There's no special type for XML strings or JSON strings, they're just strings. Serializing a *string* to the JSON format means any double quotes need to be escaped. Serliog, JSON.NET or System.Text.Json all serialize strings are just strings. If you use `JsonSerializer.Serialize(json)` with that string you'll get an escaped string as output: `"{ \u0022string\u0022 = \u0022json\u0022, \u0022boolean\u0022 = true, \u0022number\u0022 = 3}"`

Comment: The real question is why are you pre-serializing the payload? Why not just pass the object the way you did in `Logger.LogInformation("HERE IT IS {@Foo}", new { Foo = "bar" });` ? What is the actual problem you tried to solve by pre-serializing the payload?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The confusion is you are focusing on the wrong part of my question. The result of HERE IS A JSON string isn't relevant. My issue is  Logger.LogInformation("HERE IT IS {@Foo}", new { Foo = "bar" });` does not put quotes around the field names.

Comment: Serilog works as expected. So do all JSON serializers. Your expectations are wrong. You can insist your version is the right one but every other .NET developer would disagree. So would all JSON libraries

Comment: In `new { Foo = "bar" }` you're serializing an object. In `"{ \"string\" = \"json\", \"boolean\" = true, \"number\" = 3}"` you're serializing a string. There are no fields in a string. Why should any serializer treat the string the same as the object?

Comment: [This fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2PcTuf) shows that both JSON.NET and System.Text.Json serialize strings by escaping them. Neither tries to detect if the string is valid JSON. There's no such expectation. They escape them in different ways though. JSON.NET produces `"{ \"string\" = \"json\", \"boolean\" = true, \"number\" = 3}"`, what's show in the question, while System.Text.Json uses the equivalent Unicode escape sequences `"{ \u0022string\u0022 = \u0022json\u0022, \u0022boolean\u0022 = true, \u0022number\u0022 = 3}"`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated my question again, may it adds some clarity

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Confusion cleared?

Comment: Probably - you're asking why [destructuring didn't produce JSON](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data#preserving-object-structure). According to [the doc examples](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output) it should have, and the Console sink certainly did. Which sinks (including versions) did you use and how did you configure them? Post code people can actually copy and run themselves to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Great to hear. At least now we are 2 having wrong expectations and I am not alone instisting there all the other .NET developers are wrong. I provided a guide how to create a basic Serilog setup so the question has some code you can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in your `outputTemplate` - `{Message:lj}` produces literal strings and JSON objects, while the default `{Message}` produces quoted strings and the earlier C#-like object format.

Using the same output template with each sink should produce the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Do you know if Serilog has a special name for the *:lj* part and a documention for the available options and matching behaviours?

Comment: Docs are in https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#formatting-plain-text - HTH